# "Отношение к штрафу против компании" - можно так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Увидела несогласных с этим высказыванием и теперь сомневаюсь в правильности написания. Штраф против компании... Что здесь не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, "штраф против" - это не по-русски. **Штраф, наложенный на компанию**, в юридическом разговорном возможно в некоторых случаях - **"обращенный на компанию"**. Пожалуй, это все.

А **"против компании"** может быть разве что **дело** (гражданское, арбитражное), но никак не штраф.